# Javascript: Uncaught SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module

Tags: javascript, export, importerror

I'm writing a vanilla JS project and I'm encountering an issue.

test1.js:

```
export default foo;

function foo() {
    const something = "a";
}
```

test2.js:

```
import foo from test1.js;

foo();

console.log(something);
```

But when I try to run it in my browser (Firefox), I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module.`

Can anyone help? Thanks a lot!

Edit: Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you can't call a variable which is inside function. Instead of that you can write :

```
export default foo;

function foo() {
    const something = "a";
    console.log(something)
}
```

then :

```
import foo from 'test1.js';

foo();
```

and in your HTML template : `<script src="test2.js" type="module"></script>`